# How to execute a method in component after a async dispatch completes(thunk or action creator)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, redux-thunk

I am using redux with redux-thunk for async actions.

in my component I have the following code

```
class Counter extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    notify() {
        ////some logic
    }

    //
    // other code
    //
    render() {
        // code
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items,
        hasError: state.itemsHaveError,
        isLoading: state.itemsAreLoading
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemList);
```

and my code for the method is

```
function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsAreLoading(true));

        axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsAreLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(response.data)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHaveError(true)));
    };
}
```

My requirement is that in the componenentDidMount method I should be able to do like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchData('https://.....').then(res => {
       this.notify();
       /// or do something else;
   })
}
```

Can Anybody help or you need any other inputs or a working sandbox.. please reply.

Comment: `this.props.fetchData` is calling the Function that is returned by `itemsFetchData(url)`?
If so, you are returning a synchronous Function and not an AsyncFunction, i.e. `itemsFetchData(url)` returns `(dispatch) =>` and does not return `async (dispatch) =>`

Comment: can you change this above use-case and reply. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your thunk function `itemsFetchData` returns function, that is ok.

But that returned function does not return anything, you are not propagating your `return response;`. You should return the promise that is `axios.get(url)` returning:

```js
function itemsFetchData(url) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(itemsAreLoading(true));

        // you need to return promise from thunk
        return axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }

                dispatch(itemsAreLoading(false));

                return response;
            })
            .then((response) => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(response.data)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHaveError(true)));
    };
}
```

---

IMO better way than listening to `than` function on dispatched action creator, you should set something in your redux (e.g. `dataLoadedSuccessfully` to `true` in reducer handler for the action creator `itemsFetchDataSuccess`) and check for change of it in `componentDidUpdate`, e.g.:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if (this.props.dataLoadedSuccessfully && this.props.dataLoadedSuccessfully !== prevProps.dataLoadedSuccessfully) {
       this.notify();       
   }
}
```